# c++ save mat file, build log says"undefined reference to 'H5Tget_member_type'....................."

Tags: c++, linux, matlab, codeblocks, mat

When I use CodeBlock to compile a c++ program to save matrix to a mat file, the following is build log. on linux. I have set build options, the linker settings, I linked libraries, libmat.so, libeng.so, libmx.so. In search directories, in tab Compiler, I add "/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/extern/include", in tab linker, I add "/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86". What does the build log mean? How to fix it?

source code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "matrix.h"
#include "mat.h"
using namespace std;

void saveMat(mxArray* m, const string fileName){
MATFile* pmatFile = NULL;
mxArray* pMxArray = NULL;
string whole_name = fileName + ".mat";
pmatFile = matOpen(whole_name.c_str(),"w");
int row_num = mxGetM(m);
int col_num = mxGetN(m);
pMxArray = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(row_num, col_num, mxREAL);
double *data;
data = mxGetPr(m);
mxSetData(pMxArray, data);
unsigned found = fileName.find_last_of("/\\");
string name = fileName.substr(found+1);
matPutVariable(pmatFile, name.c_str(),pMxArray);
matClose(pmatFile);}
```

Build log:

```
warning: libmwfl.so, needed by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmat.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
warning: libut.so, needed by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmat.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
warning: libmx.so, needed by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmat.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
warning: libhdf5_hl.so.6, needed by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmat.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
warning: libhdf5.so.6, needed by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmat.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
warning: libmwresource_core.so, needed by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmx.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
warning: libmwi18n.so, needed by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmx.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
warning: libmwMATLAB_res.so, needed by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmx.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
warning: libboost_date_time.so.1.40.0, needed by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmx.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
warning: libboost_system.so.1.40.0, needed by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmx.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
warning: libboost_thread.so.1.40.0, needed by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmx.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
warning: libicudata.so.42, needed by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmx.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
warning: libicuuc.so.42, needed by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmx.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
warning: libicui18n.so.42, needed by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmx.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
warning: libicuio.so.42, needed by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmx.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)

/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmat.so||undefined reference to `H5Tget_member_type'
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmx.so||undefined reference to `ut_array_length'
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmat.so||undefined reference to `H5P_CLS_FILE_CREATE_g'
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmat.so||undefined reference to `H5T_NATIVE_SHORT_g'
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmx.so||undefined reference to `resource_core::BaseMsgID::getName() const'
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmat.so||undefined reference to `H5Pset_type_conv_cb'
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmat.so||undefined reference to `H5Pcreate'
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmat.so||undefined reference to `H5Tcopy'
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmx.so||undefined reference to `ut_ghash_query'
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmat.so||undefined reference to `H5Aget_space'
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmat.so||undefined reference to `H5Sget_simple_extent_dims'
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmx.so||undefined reference to `MATLAB::checkDimCommon::nonnegativeSize::nonnegativeSize()'
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmx.so||undefined reference to `utInferInstallRoot()'
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmx.so||undefined reference to `MATLAB::checkDimCommon::complexSize::complexSize()'
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmat.so||undefined reference to `H5Eset_auto2'
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmat.so||undefined reference to `utSingleConvert'
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmx.so||undefined reference to `utf16_strlen_lim'
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmat.so||undefined reference to `utGetFormatEndian'
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmx.so||undefined reference to `utf16_strcpy'
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmat.so||undefined reference to `H5Sget_simple_extent_ndims'
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmat.so||undefined reference to `H5Aget_type'
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmat.so||undefined reference to `H5Fcreate'
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmx.so||undefined reference to `MATLAB::colon::logicalInput::logicalInput()'
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmat.so||undefined reference to `H5Sset_extent_simple'
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmat.so||undefined reference to `H5Pset_layout'
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmat.so||undefined reference to `H5Sclose'
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmx.so||undefined reference to `utFinite'
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmat.so||undefined reference to `utF2cstr'
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmat.so||undefined reference to `H5Rcreate'
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmat.so||undefined reference to `utFlipFourBytes'
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmat.so||undefined reference to `H5T_NATIVE_SCHAR_g'
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmat.so||undefined reference to `H5Scopy'
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmx.so||undefined reference to `MATLAB::Cell2Struct::InvalidFieldName::InvalidFieldName(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmat.so||undefined reference to `H5Tlock'
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmat.so||undefined reference to `H5Tget_class'
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmat.so||undefined reference to `typeinfo for MathWorks::System::InternalException'
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmx.so||undefined reference to `fl::mem::aligned_heap::instance'
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmx.so||undefined reference to `utLogWarning(utWarningManagerContext*, char const*, char const*, char*, char const*, bool)'
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmat.so||undefined reference to `H5Gunlink'
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmat.so||undefined reference to `H5Tget_nmembers'
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmat.so||undefined reference to `utFree'
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmx.so||undefined reference to `ucnv_reset_4_2'
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmx.so||undefined reference to `MATLAB::getReshapeDims::notSameNumel::notSameNumel()'
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmat.so||undefined reference to `H5Acreate2'
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmx.so||undefined reference to `MathWorks::I18N::cast(MathWorks::I18N::UnicodeConverterX*)'
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmat.so||undefined reference to `utTmpnam'
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmx.so||undefined reference to `MATLAB::AddField::InvalidFieldName::InvalidFieldName(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmat.so||undefined reference to `H5Aclose'
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmat.so||undefined reference to `H5T_NATIVE_ULONG_g'
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86/libmat.so||undefined reference to `H5Pset_deflate'
More errors follow but not being shown.
Edit the max errors limit in compiler options...
=== Build finished: 50 errors, 15 warnings ===
```

Comment: I have solved the problem by adding all the warning lib*.so files to the linkersetting, and also add libboost_signals.so and libboost_filesystem.so, then there is 0 errors.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

It is because libmat and libmx calls other library files in the same folder. Try embedding the path using the linker option of

> -Wl,-rpath=LIBRARY_PATH

Specifically, on my computer I compile using the following command and it works

> g++ -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/extern/include -L/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64 sourcefile.cpp -o target  -lmat -lmx -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add "matlabroot/bin/glnxa64" to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH, where the "matlabroot" refers to the root folder of your MATLAB installation. Thus the linker may automatically find the needed libraries and no need to add so much specific library dependencies.